# How do I perform error-checking for following a hyperlink with PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: vba, error-handling, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am using a PowerPoint VBA script to open a pdf file by following a hyperlink, using the following code:

```
ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink Address:=sFile
```

The variable `sFile` is just a string with the local filepath, which previous code generates.  I want to enact some kind of error proofing that checks to make sure there is a file at the address before trying to follow the hyperlink.  If the file path is incorrect, I get an error that says "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':  Presentation (unknown member) : Cannot open the specified file."

Essentially it's telling me that the file doesn't exist (I found this error by accidentally letting the code run to the line where it opens the hyperlink before it correctly generated the entire file path string).

At any rate, in case someone is meddling and changes file names, I want to have an informative error message rather than letting the script error out.

Comment: A better name for `sFile` could be `linkPath`, or `pdfPath`, or `pdfLinkPath`; see [*Making wrong code look wrong*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) on Hungarian Notation.

Comment: I give all my variable names a lowercase character at the beginning to denote what kind of variable it is, i.e. `i` for `integer` or `s` for `string`.  From there, I give it some name, like `File` or `Counter` or whatever.

Comment: Yes, yes - that is *exactly* that "systems hungarian" does. And it's a bastardization of "apps hungarian", the *actually useful* way to use prefixes (read that article, it's excellent!). Encoding the type of a variable in its identifier serves no purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Len(Dir$(sFile)) > 0 Then
  '' The file's there, follow the link
Else
  ' The file's missing
End if
```

Comment: This code doesn't work.  I do not have a complete, explicit file path spelled out (in case someone moves the entire directory the user is working in).  So, my string is something like this `"Sub Directory 1\Sub Directory 2\Filename.pdf"`

Comment: If you don't know where the target file is, you'll need to calculate it. You can extract the path from ActivePresentation.Path and prefix it to your sFile variable.

Comment: @JamieGarroch that worked after I concatenated the presentation path:  `If Len(Dir$(ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & sFile)) > 0 Then`...